# Visual and sound notification calendar application for Android

Tags: applications, notifications, xiaomi, calendar

I need a calendar application to give me an alarm at a certain date and time but I need visual and sound notification in the same time, like an alarm with text. Can Google Calendar notifications use sounds?
I have Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 Pro 5G, Android 11.